# Embedded games of html5 are not working when html code is in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

*Actually I embed HTML5 games in my html page. They work fine, but when I put that HTML code in my Ruby on Rails project then the games don't start.*

*Code to call modal*

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="gameButton"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-
        fullscreen" data-gamesrc="http://www.fupa.com/swf/counting-123-
        fish/FISH.swf">
            <figure>
                <div class="imgwrapper">
                    <img src="Images/logo.png" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                </div>
                <center>
                    <figcaption style="background:#333;">
                        <h4 style="text-decoration:none;">Chess</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </center>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
```

*And the embedded code for a game is in a modal, so that when a user click on a game picture modal opens and a game start in a modal.
Modal code is:*

```
<div class="modal modal-fullscreen fade" id="modal-fullscreen" style="opacity:0.95;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-body" id="panel_home_images">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="close" style="color: black;" 
                    data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>                            
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                            <embed id="gameHolder" wmode="transparent" 
                            base="http://external.kongregate-
                            games.com/gamez/0022/3733/live/" 
                            src="http://external.kongregate-
                           games.com/gamez/0022/3733/live/embeddable_223733.swf" 
                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you've forgotten embedded code -))

Comment: Can you share the code used to display the modal?

Comment: I edit my question. Please tell me the problem